# session_start() giving error for session_destroy() in PHP 8

Tags: php, session, php-8

All of a sudden, my custom session handlers' session's session_start() is not working. I had to include destroy after upgrading to PHP 8. It isn't an issue in PHP 7.4.

```
private static function load()
{
    # session_module_name("user");
    session_set_save_handler(['\CB\Session', 'open'],
                             ['\CB\Session', 'close'],
                             ['\CB\Session', 'read'],
                             ['\CB\Session', 'write'],
                             ['\CB\Session', 'remove'],
                             ['\CB\Session', 'gc'],
                             ['\CB\Session', 'destroy']
                             );        
    
    session_start(); // Error here
}

public static function destroy($id)
{
    return TRUE;
}
```

> Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to
> function CB\Session::destroy(), 0 passed and exactly 1 expected in
> Session.php:
> Stack trace:
> #0 [internal function]: CB\Session::destroy()
> #1 /path/CB/Session.php(35): session_start()
> #2 /path/CB/Session.php(17): CB\Session::load()

Why is it talking about session_destroy for session_start (login) ? My logout is working.

EDIT : For some reason CB\Session::destroy() is getting called before session_start()

Comment: Where is `destroy` being called? Which exact line is it referring to?

Comment: In my act_logout function. `$_SESSION = array();

if (isset($_COOKIE[session_name()]))
setcookie(session_name(), '', time()-42000, '/');

@session_destroy(); # Throws an error in PHP7, so hence the @
`

Comment: Where are you calling `Session::destroy()`? How is the class in your question integrated into PHP's session handling?

Comment: I am calling session_destroy(); only in act_logout() which is called when someone clicks the logout link. Nowhere else. This is what I am trying to modify for PHP 8 - https://github.com/anjanesh/CB/blob/master/Session.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the session_set_save_handler manual page](https://www.php.net/session_set_save_handler) the arguments are:

1. $open
2. $close
3. $read
4. $write
5. $destroy
6. $gc
7. (optional) $create_sid
8. (optional) $validate_sid
9. (optional) $update_timestamp

The method names you have provided are:

1. 'open'
2. 'close'
3. 'read'
4. 'write'
5. 'remove'
6. 'gc'
7. 'destroy'

So the method called for the session "destroy" event is `\CB\Session::remove`, and the `\CB\Session::destroy` method is being called for the "create_sid" event. Since the create_sid callback is called without any arguments, this is giving you the error you're seeing.

At the beginning of your question you said:

> I had to include destroy after upgrading to PHP 8.

Since what you've actually included is a broken create_sid callback, whatever problem you thought you were solving may still need solving, but that would be a different question. The solution to your current error is to remove the erroneous `['\CB\Session', 'destroy']` line from your code.

Comment: Thank You IMSoP - I replaced `remove` with `destroy` and returned TRUE - it worked.